# Setting a quartz property programmatically in a jboss seam project

Tags: java, jboss7.x, quartz-scheduler

i have a seam web app deployed in jboss 7 and it uses quartz to schedule jobs, currently i'm using a properties file called 'seam.quartz.properties' that is packaged inside the ear file to provide quartz with the required settings. my aim here is to be able to set some properties programmatically(from an xml file or a database) on deployment and overriding whats in the properties file or maybe removing the property from the file.
is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, in my project i have the file 'seam.quartz.prperties' where i specify many properties for the scheduler that i intend to create, one of the properties is the 'org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName' (i named my scheduler "engineScheduler") so when getting my scheduler i do this:

```
DirectSchedulerFactory directSchedulerFactory = DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance();
Scheduler scd = directSchedulerFactory.getScheduler("engineScheduler");
```

and it will get me the scheduler with the properties i provided in the file.
the solution is to use 'createScheduler' instead of 'getScheduler' like the following:

```
createScheduler(java.lang.String schedulerName, java.lang.String schedulerInstanceId, org.quartz.spi.ThreadPool threadPool, org.quartz.spi.JobStore jobStore)
```

the thread count is an attribute inside the ThreadPool instance that needs to be created first then given to the method(createScheduler).